# Display data in combo box?

Tags: java, jdbc

i have a table with 4 columns.In my GUI i have 2 textfields(Patient_ID and Date) and 2 combo box(for charges and time(format: "hh:mm")) to display the data from my table.

```
col1-patient_ID   
col2-charges  Type-Number
col3-time  Type-TIMESTAMP
col4-date Type-Date
```

my query is:: 
(Select col1 , col2 , col3 , col4 from  where col1=?)

now what i want is, when user enters the Patient_ID in textfield and click on button "DISPLAY" ,the data from the table(Oracle express edition ) should be fetched and displayed in respective textFields and Combo boxex.
I don't know how to fetch the data from col2 and col3 into respective combo box.
Please help!!
Thanks.

Comment: are you using any java web/database framework ? you can run query select * from table where col1=someID. Then you iterate over the resultset and form the combo box and display it to the front-end.

Comment: what framework you are talking about,didn't get you.

Comment: I am asking whther you are using any web framework ?